# java + converting String to Double appends trailing zero after decimal

Tags: java

I am not able to understand, why this code retursn 10.0, rather than 10

```
Double inputDouble = Double.valueOf("10");  
System.out.println(inputDouble);
```

The requirement is 
if I pass 10.00, output should be  10.00
if I pass 10.0, output should be  10.0
and if I pass 10, output should be 10

is it possible and in a clean way

Comment: `10.00` == `10.0`==`10`, so no.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The requirement is if I pass 10.00, output should be 10.00

Then you're using the wrong type. `double` has no notion of significant digits - there's no difference between 10, 10.0 and 10.00.

You should try using `BigDecimal` instead:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("10")); // Prints 10
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("10.0")); // Prints 10.0
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("10.00")); // Prints 10.00
```

Aside from anything else, even if `double` *did* try to preserve insignificant digits, it would be thinking about *binary* digits as it's a floating *binary* point type. If you're interested in the actual *decimal* digits that you're provided with, that's another reason to use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: alright, so what can be done to remove/discard the trailing zeros in the output, which is of type Double. So that Double inputDouble = Double.valueOf("10"); returns 10

Comment: @Naroji: You can use [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) for that.